# How to add an animation gif to a javascript program

Tags: javascript

I am very new to the world of coding and I am in a coding bootcamp learning about JavaScript. We created a number guessing game and I am trying to add an animation that will run after the correct answer is entered. I have googled a few times trying to find the answer, but I was looking to see if there is an easier way. I have included a copy of the program below. If I wanted an animation to appear after the correct answer is entered, how could I do that?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Number Guessing Game</title>
    </head>
    <body style='background-color:black'>
        <h1>Number Guessing Game</h1>
        <button type="button" onclick="runGame()">Start Game</button>
        <script>
            function runGame() {
                let guessString ='';
                let guessNumber = 0;
                let correct = false;
                let numTries = 0;

                const randomNumber = Math.random() * 100;
                const randomInteger = Math.floor(randomNumber);
                const target = randomInteger + 1;

                do {
                    guessString = prompt('I am thinking of a number in the range 1 to 100.\n\nWhat is the number?');
                    guessNumber = +guessString;
                    numTries += 1; 
                    correct = checkGuess(guessNumber, target, numTries);
                } while (!correct);

                alert('You got it! The number was ' + target + '.\n\nIt took you ' + numTries + ' tries to guess correctly.');
            }

            function checkGuess(guessNumber, target, numTries) {
                let correct = false;

                if (isNaN(guessNumber)) {
                    alert('Alright smarty pants!\n\nPlease enter a number in the 1-100 range.');
                } else if ((guessNumber < 1) || (guessNumber > 100)) {
                    alert('Please enter an integer in the 1-100 range.');
                } else if (guessNumber > target) {
                    alert('Your number is too large!\n\nGuess Number: ' + numTries + '.');
                } else if (guessNumber < target) {
                    alert('Your number is too small!\n\nGuess Number: ' + numTries + '.');
                } else {
                    correct = true;
                }
                return correct;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please don't use `alert()` in a code snippet especially if it is in a loop. It renders the page useless and causes problems trying to answer your question or add comments. Either way, in your `checkGuess` function where `correct = true` you could create an `img` element: `let img = document.createElement("img")`, add the image source: `img.src = "yourAnimation.gif"`, then append it to the document: `document.body.appendChild(img)`

Comment: Thanks! I will figure out a way to get rid of the alert() in the code.

Answer (score 0):

To be able do that you need to learn [DOM Manipulation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction).

Here is a simple example :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Number Guessing Game</title>
    </head>
    <body style='background-color:black'>
        <h1>Number Guessing Game</h1>
        <button type="button" onclick="runGame()">Start Game</button>
        <script>
            function runGame() {
                let guessString ='';
                let guessNumber = 0;
                let correct = false;
                let numTries = 0;

                const randomNumber = Math.random() * 100;
                const randomInteger = Math.floor(randomNumber);
                const target = randomInteger + 1;

                do {
                    guessString = prompt('I am thinking of a number in the range 1 to 100.\n\nWhat is the number?');
                    guessNumber = +guessString;
                    numTries += 1; 
                    correct = checkGuess(guessNumber, target, numTries);
                } while (!correct);

                alert('You got it! The number was ' + target + '.\n\nIt took you ' + numTries + ' tries to guess correctly.');
                // add your gif to the dom
                // create an img element
                const img = document.createElement("img")
                // set the source of the gif
                img.src = "https://i0.wp.com/badbooksgoodtimes.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/plankton-correct-gif.gif?fit=400%2C287"
                // add the img element to the dom
                // in this case we are gonna add it after the 'start game' button, so
                // select the button element
                const btn = document.querySelector("button")
                // insert the img element after the button
                btn.parentNode.insertBefore(img, btn.nextSibling);
                
            }

            function checkGuess(guessNumber, target, numTries) {
                let correct = false;

                if (isNaN(guessNumber)) {
                    alert('Alright smarty pants!\n\nPlease enter a number in the 1-100 range.');
                } else if ((guessNumber < 1) || (guessNumber > 100)) {
                    alert('Please enter an integer in the 1-100 range.');
                } else if (guessNumber > target) {
                    alert('Your number is too large!\n\nGuess Number: ' + numTries + '.');
                } else if (guessNumber < target) {
                    alert('Your number is too small!\n\nGuess Number: ' + numTries + '.');
                } else {
                    correct = true;
                }
                return correct;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

keep going and good luck.